# sort list by second name but if second name is the same, sort by first name

Tags: java, sorting

I want to build a method to sort a list by second name, but if I have two similar objects with second name, my method sort by first name only similar objects.

For example this is my list:

```
 List<Person> p = new ArrayList<Person>();
    p.add(new Person("Konrath", "Will"));
    p.add(new Person("Pavol","Rower"));
    p.add(new Person("Abie", "Backi"));
    p.add(new Person("Bartie", "Rower"));
    return p;
```

I want such result:

```
 List<Person> p = new ArrayList<Person>();
    p.add(new Person("Abie", "Backi"));
    p.add(new Person("Bartie", "Rower"));
    p.add(new Person("Pavol", "Rower")); 
    p.add(new Person("Konrath","Will"));
    return p;
```

When I have the same second name like "Rower", this method sorts by first name.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: what you have tired ? so far ?

Comment: Sorting an object is essentially something basic, with implementing [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface. There are plenty information on the internet about this interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such as Collections.sort or Arrays.sort) to allow precise control over the sort order.

Below a `Comparator` implementation valid since java 1.2.
Starting from java 8 it is possible to have a much more shorter implementation as commented by Robin Topper.

```
public class SecondThanFirstComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
   public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
       // Handle nulls

       if (p1.getSecondName().equals(p2.getSecondName())) {
           return p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
       } else {
           return p1.getSecondName().compareTo(p2.getSecondName());
       }
       return 0;
     }
}


List<Person> p = ...;

...

Collections.sort(p, new SecondThanFirstComparator());
// From here p list is sorted
```

Comment: Bit shorter: `Collections.sort(p, Comparator.comparing((Person p) -> p.getSecondName()).thenComparing((Person p) -> p.getFirstName));`

Comment: thank you guys, it does work :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like that (you didn't provide `Person` bean details, so getters names are only my guess):

```
    p.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        int sc = o1.getSname().compareTo(o2.getSname());
        return sc != 0 ? sc : o1.getFname().compareTo(o2.getFname());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your person object should implement the comparable interface:

> Lists (and arrays) of objects that implement this interface can be sorted automatically by Collections.sort (and Arrays.sort). Objects that implement this interface can be used as keys in a sorted map or as elements in a sorted set, without the need to specify a comparator.

The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.